# Android example project compilation failed?

Tags: java, android

I'm new at Android world. Just learning. I want to study build [this](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/mini-notepad/comment-page-1/#comment-1127) project. But it fails for all R.*  members and so other reasons. After searching the web I found several blogs to fix generated R.java files. But I couldn't fix it. Maybe I don't much about Android and Java. Can anybody make a Eclipse project out of this example which is build properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your project. If that won't work check your xml files for any error. That's the most common reason for getting errors related to `R.java*`.